# How do I do a scan for BLE devices on a specific channel using hcitool lescan?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I tried looking at the manual for hcitool but there seems to be no explanation as to how the channel can be set. By default, it seems like hcitool will only scan on channel 37(one of the 3 advertising channels) when the lescan command is issued. How do I get hcitool to scan on other channels?(e.g 38/39)